# Feynman diagram of muon pair production

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

[image]

Hi to everyone. I don't understand why the diagram in which final antimuon and muon are exchanged is not possible (so having in the upper part positron and muon, downwards electron and antimuon). It seems in all diagrams I seen that in the upper part I must have only antiparticles, and in the lower part only particles (or vice-versa).

Is there a specific rule?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here, if you mean that $p_2$ is an electron and $p_1$is a position there is nothing stopping you from drawing it that way at all.

Comment: See this answer - not exactly the same question but I explained in it when ST and U channels are possible. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/759848/why-there-is-only-t-channel-for-u-bar-d-rightarrow-u-bar-d-scattering/759850#759850 . In short, it's because the feynman diagram calculates the matrix element for producing a $\mu^+$ with momentum $k_2$, it does not calculate the matrix element for making a $\mu^-$ with momentum $k_2$. There's certainly no reason the $\mu^+$ has to be drawn on top... in fact it doesn't even mean anything.

Comment: What I do not completely understand is: if I deal with muon pair production, in principle I have four different diagrams, obtained by exchanging initial momenta and final momenta of particles involved in the process. So according to my line of reasoning,  in the first diagram I expect electron with p1, positron p2, muon k1, antimuon k2. In the second one electron with p2, positron p1, muon k2, antimuon k1 and so on. So why I have just one diagram for all these possibilities? Are all four possible diagrams in some way "equivalent"?

Comment: Yes, now it is clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The u channel diagram is not possible because the muon and anti muon are not identical particles.

Also the arrows labeling $p_i, k_i$ are extraneous, and a bit confusing.  E.g, which way would it point in the t channel?

Finally, as a former DISer, $k$ usually labels the electron, unless you’re in EMC, where the muon is the probe.